# How to add MinterRole during Truffle deployment?

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

I'm currently at the end of the Ethereum Blockchain Developer Bootcamp With Solidity (2021) course on Udemy and the final project is to change a fixed supply Token to a Mintable token. We're using Solidity 0.6.1 here. I'm having some issues adding the MinterRole of the token during deployment. I'm also lousy at Javascript (working on improving that. Just need to get through this final project first). Here's how I'm attempting to do it in 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
let token = await MyToken.deployed();
await token.methods.addMinter(deployer.address).call({from: deployer.address});
```

When I attempt to migrate I'm getting the following error.

`TypeError: token.methods.addMinter is not a function`

However if I console.log(token.methods), there it is right there:

```
{
  'addMinter(address)': [Function] {
    call: [Function],
    sendTransaction: [Function],
    estimateGas: [Function],
    request: [Function]
  },
```

So any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: As requested here is my entire 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var MyToken = artifacts.require("MyToken.sol");
var MyTokenSale = artifacts.require("MyTokenSale");
var MyKycContract = artifacts.require("KycContract");
require("dotenv").config({path: "../.env"});

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
    let addr = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await deployer.deploy(MyToken);
    await deployer.deploy(MyKycContract);
    await deployer.deploy(MyTokenSale, 1, addr[0], MyToken.address, MyKycContract.address);

    let token = await MyToken.deployed();
    console.log(token.methods);
    await token.methods.addMinter(deployer.address).call({from: deployer.address});
   

}
```

Edit2:

Ok I seem to have solved it. I was trying to add the deployer address when I should have been passing in the Crowdsale (myTokenSale) address. My experimenting with .call was out of desperation. This seems to have worked.

```
let token = await MyToken.deployed();
let tokenSale = await MyTokenSale.deployed();
await token.addMinter(tokenSale.address);
```

Comment: It seems like you're combining Truffle ([Mytoken.deployed()](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#-code-mycontract-deployed-code-)) and Web3 ([token.methods](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#id26)), which can cause a situation where the contract is instantiated in Truffle but not in Web3. It's a better practice to interact with a contract using just one library... Can you share the whole code of your `2_deploy_contracts.js`?

Comment: That actually gave me a huge clue. I updated my post above and it seems to work now.